# Factorise numbers

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I've started learning Clojure a few days ago and I wrote this code that factorises numbers. How do I make it better? Is there any way to avoid doing it with a loop? Is that how I am supposed to code in Clojure?

```
(defn classify [n]
  (loop [n n
         i 2
         f []]
    (cond
      (= n i) (conj f i)
      (= (mod n i) 0) (recur (/ n i) 2 (conj f i))
      :else (recur n (inc i) f))))
```

Comment: This is functional. `loop` is the functional way to "loop" in Clojure. `doseq` for example would be the "bad", imperative way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a slightly more functional way to express your algorithm is ...

```
(defn classify [n]
  (letfn [(factors-from [i from]
            (cond
              (= i 1) '()
              (zero? (mod i from)) (cons from (factors-from (quot i from) from))
              :else (recur i (inc from))))]
   (factors-from n 2)))
```

- The local function `factors-from` plays the role of the `loop`.
- The recursive call when we have found a factor saves us carrying the
  sequence of factors as a parameter.
- We use `quot` instead of `/` for the division, since it is simpler.
- The terminal case is `1`instead of `from`. This gives the correct
  answer of an empty factor list when `n` is `1`.
- The normal case, when we don't find a factor, is a straight tail
  recursion, hence can be a `recur`.

There is no danger of running out of stack space, since the smallest number that could do so is about 2^10000, far beyond anything long arithmetic could deal with.

Comment: Thank you! I can learn a lot by reading this code and trying out the functions you used.